# Connection between proximal mapping and strong convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, proximal-operators

I need some helps to solve this proof, any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

> Suppose $\mathbf{x}_k$=$Prox_{\eta}\,g(\mathbf{y}_k-\eta\nabla f(\mathbf{y}_k))$, prove that:
> \begin{align*}
> g(\mathbf{x}_k) \leq g(\mathbf{y}_k) - \langle \nabla f(\mathbf{y}_k),\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{y}_k \rangle-\frac{1}{2\eta}\|\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{y}_k\|_2^2
> \end{align*}

Here is my attempt: I try to first solve the proximal mapping by taking the optimal condition w.r.t. to $w\in dom(g)$, for which I got $Prox_{\eta}\,g(\mathbf{y}_k-\eta\nabla f(\mathbf{y}_k))=w=\mathbf{y}_k-\eta(\nabla g(w)+\nabla f(\mathbf{y}_k))$.

Then I try to substitute this into the definition of 1-strong convexity for function $g$:
\begin{align*}
&g(\mathbf{y}_k)\geq g(\mathbf{x}_k)+\langle\nabla g(x),\mathbf{y}_k-\mathbf{x}_k \rangle+\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{y}_k-\mathbf{x}_k\|_2^2 \\
&g(\mathbf{x}_k) \leq g(\mathbf{y}_k)-\langle\nabla g(x),\eta(\nabla g(w)+\nabla f(\mathbf{y}_k) \rangle+\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{y}_k-\mathbf{x}_k\|_2^2
\end{align*}
But this looks like a bad approach to me and I don't how to proceed beyond that.

Comment: This looks like an inequality that is used in a convergence proof for the proximal gradient method. Maybe reading such a convergence proof will shed some light. (I'd try first looking at Vandenberghe's UCLA EE 236c notes to find the relevant convergence proof.)